# ASP.NET Razor mixing with javascript literal

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My problem is when I try to setup the onclick handler, updatePage(), is there a way to inject a Razor variables value as a parameter to the updatePage() function like I'm trying to do below? What I have below of course is a compile error caused by the updatePage portion.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index",  
    new { page = iPageT + 1 },   
    new { @class = "paging-links-submit", onclick = "updatePage("iPageT++"); return false;" })
```

Comment: Please provide at least the compiler error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concat your server side processed razor argument with the client side javascript function call. Add the `+` like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index",  
    new { page = iPageT + 1 },   
    new { @class = "paging-links-submit", onclick = "updatePage(" + iPageT + "); return false;" })
```

I would prefer to increment `iPageT` before calling `@Html.ActionLink()`, but this is up to you.

Comment: Was I able to help you with your problem? If so, please [mark my reply as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thank you sir! =)